# How to display second text from right side using substring in c#

Tags: c#, substring

I am trying display text from right side. For Example **57001 to 58000 Lbs (D)** In that text I need to display only **'D'** I have tried using substring my code is below

```
 mystring = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 2);
```

for the above code answer is  **'D)'** but I need to display only **'D'** Please help me.

Comment: Search before post: [Substring C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please edit and explain what you need. If i'm not mistaken, you want to find the first text RTL?

Comment: Just use the other overload of substring of index and length

Comment: `mystring[mystring.Length - 2]` probably?

Comment: `mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 2,1);` will solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to specify 2 parameters when calling the method [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

1 - where does it starts.

2 - how long should it be.

Therefore,

```
mystring.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
```

In your case :

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 2, 1);
```

If you don't specify its length it will take by default the whole string coming right next to your startIndex (included).

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 2,1);
```

The second Parameter is the length
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)